# The user name or password is incorrect | System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, mscorlib

I am getting an error on file read only when the API is hosted on IIS. But I am able to access the same path from the host but it fails when hosted. Please advise.

Code:

```
var stream = new FileStream(param, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
Int32 length = stream.Length > Int32.MaxValue ? Int32.MaxValue : Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
//Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ss);
                
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
return Ok(file);
```

Comment: My guess is that IIS is running under another user, such as NetworkService. And if the file is for example located in your Documents folder, that user has no rights there. Maybe this helps: https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/finding_the_name_of_the_user_that_runs_a_process_in_iis.htm

Comment: The files is from a shared network location. I have another network path and it works there but not for the new path that is being supplied.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 "I am able to access the same path from the host but it fails when hosted" just matches the typical differences.